# GenericJDBCException in HSQL

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb

I have an entity called `ProdTransaction`. I am saving two records of type `ProdTransaction`. Both the two inserts succeed when run independently. I mean

```
tranDAO.save(record1) //alone works
tranDAO.save(record2) //alone works
```

but together running them as

```
tranDAO.save(record1)
tranDAO.save(record2)
```

HSQL throws a `GenericJDBCException` error.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ProdTransaction")
public class ProdTransactionextends PersistentObject implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Embedded
private ProdTranPK id;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Column(name = "REC_ID")
private Long recId;

@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date date1;

@Column(length = 1)
private String comment;
}
```

I have verified the data and it's all fine. When I run against HSQL I get:

> GenericJDBCException: could not execute JDBC batch update.

But if I connect to my physical DB, and run with the same sequence, it works fine. What could be the problem in HSQL? I am using version 1.8.

Comment: HSQLDB does support batch.Try adding a flush after each statement.Also add logging to see the exact SQL that is going to HSQLDB and copy paste that directly into HSQLDB Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HSQLDB batching bug was fixed, now it works ok. Problem is that if you have an error, such as a problem with your SQL statement etc, you'll only get a generic exception that doesn't really tell you anything. What I like to do is have a helper class that can execute SQL queries in batch mode and individually, and I switch to individual queries when I get weird errors from batch mode. Try that, maybe it's just a simple mistake in your SQL

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible to [disable batching in hibernate](http://inoio.de/blog/2012/11/16/how-to-get-rid-of-hibernate-genericjdbcexception/).  In the hibernate session configuration, set:

```
hibernate.jdbc.factory_class=org.hibernate.jdbc.NonBatchingBatcherFactory
```